# Sobolev spaces on different domains

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $U\subset\subset V\subset\subset \mathbb R^n$. Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ such that $f=0$ ouside $U$. If $f\in W^{k,p}(U)$, is it true that $f\in W^{k,p}(V)$ ? or any counterexample ? It might be not true, or otherwise, the extension theorem of section 5.4 in Evans' PDE book is meaningless (may take $E=$identity).

Comment: By extension theorem do you mean $E : W^{k,p}(U) \to W^{k,p}(V)$?

Comment: It is not true but I cannot come up with an example right now; Just truncating $f$ to $0$ around $\partial U$ will not 'preserve derivatives'. You may, of course, extend $f$ to $V$ that preserves derivatives around $\partial U$ and is equal to $f$ on $U$, by using the extension thm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you do not pose any 'global' conditions on $f$, this is not true. An easy counterexample is
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{for } x \in U,\\ 0 & \text{else}.\end{cases}$$
This satisfies your conditions, but does not belong to $W^{k,p}(V)$ if $k > 0$.